# how to change the AlertDialogue box title back color in Android?

Tags: android

im new to android development i want to change the title backcolor of alerdialogue box in android which is by default is black ,kindly tell how to change this any help in this regards is greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3995058/422931) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

A  tutorial:

- http://sagistech.blogspot.com/2010/07/colors-in-alertdialog.html