# How to build a custom Dialog "Button area"

Tags: android, view, dialog, customization, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to get a custom Dialog to work. It should have no Title, a basic TextMessage and my Custom Layout where normally Buttons appear. 
I tried to accomplish this with an AlertDialog.Builder, extending Dialog, call methods on the Dialog and still not get the expected result.

This is the layout, I Like to use as a custom ButtonArea (layout/dialog_footer):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/dialog_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/never_show_again"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/dialog_button_background"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dialog_checkbox"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/dialog_button_background"
        android:paddingBottom="-10dip">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_btn_positive"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_btn_negative"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="@string/btn_cancel" 
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The simplest try goes like this:

```
AlertDialog.Buiilder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setMessage("my Message");
Dialog dialog = builder.create();

//builder has `setView for Message or setCustomTitle, but no setCustomFooter
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_footer);

//either NullPointer Exception
dialog.addContentView(footer, footer.getLayoutParams);
//or AndroidRuntimeException (requestFeature() must be called befoire adding content)
dialog.addContentView(footer, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

If I try to emulate the "MessageArea" by putting a TextView on Top of my Layout it works, but has very ugly black borders at the bottom (I guess its the custom Dialog-Theme).

Whats the best way to keep the "look and feel" of a System Dialog, but replace the Buttons with my own View and handle anything myself?

Comment: Why not just design the whole view the way you want it - with the message and buttons - and then use `setView`?  And not show any standard buttons at all.

Comment: as I stated `setView` will work, but has a ugly black border I cannot get rid of

Comment: To get rid of the black border, use `setView(myView, 0, 0, 0, 0)`.  Those 0's specify the margin for the view.

Comment: I must stay compatible to Android 2.1, so there is no such method setView(View, int, int, int, int). Not in Dialog.Builder and not in Dialog itself

Comment: You're clearly missing something.  [`setView (View view, int viewSpacingLeft, int viewSpacingTop, int viewSpacingRight, int viewSpacingBottom)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setView(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) on `AlsertDialog` is available from API level 3 (Android 1.6)

Comment: oh, sorry, your're right! Its an AlertDialog Method, not in Dialog or AlertDialog.Builder... I simply missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of Aleks G I managed to get it work:

the code flow goes like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setMessage("MyMessage");

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.apo_plus_dialog_footer, null);

AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.setView(footerView, 0,0,0,0);

if (!hasTitle){
    alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}

alertDialog.show();
```

just in case someone wants to have a similar Dialog behavior than me.

Answer (score 0):

Hello friend please check this post it may be helpful for your problem

[Android - Custom AlertDialog Background Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995058/android-custom-alertdialog-background-color)

Here which i have build my own Custom Edit Dialog for my app see the Layout code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Name: "
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtDelName"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Contact No :"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtDelAge"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinDiagDept"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:prompt="@string/Rel_prompt"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

And here is the alert dialog code

```
    public class Alerts {

    public static AlertDialog ShowEditDialog(final Context con,final Emergencydb emp)
    {
AlertDialog.Builder b=new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
b.setTitle("Emergency Contact Details");
LayoutInflater li=LayoutInflater.from(con);
View v=li.inflate(R.layout.editdialog, null);

b.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_get);

b.setView(v);
final TextView txtName=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtDelName);
final TextView txtAge=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtDelAge);
final Spinner spin=(Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinDiagDept);
Utilities.ManageDeptSpinner(con, spin);
for(int i=0;i<spin.getCount();i++)
{
    long id=spin.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
    if(id==emp.getDept())
    {
        spin.setSelection(i, true);
        break;
    }
}


txtName.setText(emp.getName());
txtAge.setText(String.valueOf(emp.getAge()));

b.setPositiveButton("Modify", new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        emp.setName(txtName.getText().toString());
        emp.setAge(String.valueOf(txtAge.getText().toString()));                                    emp.setDept((int)spin.getItemIdAtPosition(spin.getSelectedItemPosition()));

        try
        {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        DatabaseHelper db=new DatabaseHelper(con);
        db.UpdateEmp(emp);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Modified Successfully",                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }       
});

b.setNeutralButton("Delete", new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        DatabaseHelper db=new DatabaseHelper(con);
        db.DeleteEmp(emp);

    }
});
b.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

return b.create();
//diag.show();

     }

    protected static Context getBaseContext() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
      }

        public static void ShowEmpAddedAlert(
    android.view.View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }



}
```

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?

Comment: As he wants to build a Custom Dialog so i created a Custom Dialog edit box where user can edit his details using it, so i posted the code which any helpful to him ....

Comment: His question is not about customer dialog.  He doesn't need one.  Instead, he wants a standard dialog with custom button layout.